Environment variables as parameter of type object in Azure DevOps pipelines
I'm working on an Azure DevOps pipeline where I need to pass environment variables to a job template. Instead of passing these environment variables as a single string, I want to pass them as an object for better manageability.
As a string (current approach - works but it's hacky):
parameters:
  - name: envVars
    type: string
    default: ""

...

- script |
    ${{ parameters.envVars}} <rest of command>
...

As an object:
parameters:
  - name: envVars
    type: object
    default: { ENV_VAR: "value_example" }

- script |
    <rest of command>
  env:
    ${{ parameters.envVars }} 

In the second case, I would hope that Azure DevOps unwraps the envVars object properly and would be equivalent to having
env:
  ENV_VAR: "value_example"
  ENV_VAR_B: "other_value"
  ...
  # can still have other environment variables here that are not present in envVars

However, I'm not finding any proper documentation from Azure DevOps around this and not exactly sure what would be the best way to unwrap the envVars object and pass it to the script. Any guidance or improvements on this setup would be greatly appreciated!

As an alternative to Kevin's answer, you can use an ${{ each ... }} loop to iterate over the properties of a parameter or, as an alternative, over an array of custom objects.
Example 1
Iterating over all the properties of a parameter like a dictionary (kind of), and accessing the key (property name) and corresponding value:
parameters:
  - name: envVars
    type: object
    default:  
      foo: foo value
      bar: bar value

trigger: none

steps:
  - checkout: none
  - script: |
      echo "$foo"
      echo "$bar"
      echo "$anotherVariable"
    displayName: Display environment variables
    env:
      anotherVariable: anotherValue
      ${{ each variable in parameters.envVars }}:
        ${{ variable.Key }}: ${{ variable.Value }}

Example 2
Iterating over an array of custom objects:
parameters:
  - name: envVars
    type: object
    default:  
      - name: foo
        value: foo value
      - name: bar
        value: bar value

trigger: none

steps:
  - checkout: none
  - script: |
      echo "$foo"
      echo "$bar"
      echo "$anotherVariable"
    displayName: Display environment variables
    env:
      anotherVariable: anotherValue
      ${{ each variable in parameters.envVars }}:
        ${{ variable.name }}: ${{ variable.value }}


Hi Rui. This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!


Instead of passing these environment variables as a single string, I want to pass them as an object for better manageability.

To meet your requirement, you can use the following Parameters format to define the object env value.
parameters:
  - name: envVars
    type: object
    default:  
     ENV_VAR: "value_example" 
     ENV_VAR_B: "other_value"
steps:
- script: |
     echo $ENV_VAR
     echo $ENV_VAR_B
  env:
   ${{ parameters.envVars }}

But if you use the parameters in the env field, it doesn't support adding additional env values.
For example:
- script: |
     echo $ENV_VAR
     echo $ENV_VAR_B
  env:
   ${{ parameters.envVars }}
   test: test1

It will show the error below:

For a workaround, you can define the variables in YAML pipeline and the variable will be mapped to the environment variable automatically.
For example:
variables:
  test: test1
parameters:
  - name: envVars
    type: object
    default:  
     ENV_VAR: "value_example" 
     ENV_VAR_B: "other_value"
steps:
- script: |
     echo $ENV_VAR
     echo $ENV_VAR_B
     echo $test
  env:
   ${{ parameters.envVars }}

Result:

